# OnKillFocus not being called

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CFormView derived class where I want to call a method when focus is lost.

Tried this:

MyClass.cpp

```
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(EN_KILLFOCUS, OnKillFocus)

void CMyClass::OnKillFocus()
{
}
```

MyClass.h

```
afx_msg void OnKillFocus();
```

But my method is not being called, is there some way to achieve what I want?

Comment: In case this is what you're trying to implement: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant message and functions are

```
ON_WM_KILLFOCUS()
```

and

```
afx_msg void OnKillFocus(CWnd* pNewWnd);
```

---

`EN_KILLFOCUS` and other `EN_XXX` notifications are specific to Edit controls. For example:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_EDIT1, OnMyFunction)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void OnMyFunction();
```

Comment: I get Invalid type conversion when adding `ON_WM_KILLFOCUS()` in the message map

Comment: Make sure you remove the other `OnKillFocus();` which had been declared earlier.